# Guaranteed message delivery asynchronously

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I wrote a code that guarantees the delivery of messages and their processing. But it works in one thread. 
How to refactor code so that it works in **parallel threads or asynchronously**? In this case, messages **must be guaranteed to be delivered even if the application crashes**. They will be delivered after a new start of the application or with the help of other running instances of this application.

Producer:

```
@Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
@EventListener(condition = "#event.queue")
public void start(GenericSpringEvent<RenderQueueObject> event) {
    RenderQueueObject renderQueueObject = event.getWhat();
    send(RENDER_NAME, renderQueueObject);
}
private void send(String routingKey, Object queue) {
    try {
        log.info("SEND message");
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(routingKey, objectMapper.writeValueAsString(queue));
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        log.warn("Can't send event!", e);
    }
}
```

Consumer

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class RenderRabbitEventListener extends RabbitEventListener {

    private final ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

    @RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(value = @Queue(Queues.RENDER_NAME),
                                             exchange = @Exchange(value = Exchanges.EXC_RENDER_NAME, type = "topic"),
                                             key = "render.#")
    )
    public void onMessage(Message message, Channel channel) {
        String routingKey = parseRoutingKey(message);

        log.debug(String.format("Event %s", routingKey));

        RenderQueueObject queueObject = parseRender(message, RenderQueueObject.class);
        handleMessage(queueObject);
    }
    public void handleMessage(RenderQueueObject render) {
        GenericSpringEvent<RenderQueueObject> springEvent = new GenericSpringEvent<>(render);
        springEvent.setRender(true);
        eventPublisher.publishEvent(springEvent);
    }
}

public class Exchanges {
    public static final String EXC_RENDER_NAME = "render.exchange.topic";
    public static final TopicExchange EXC_RENDER = new TopicExchange(EXC_RENDER_NAME, true, false);
}

public class Queues {
    public static final String RENDER_NAME = "render.queue.topic";
    public static final Queue RENDER = new Queue(RENDER_NAME);
}
```

And so my message is processed. If I add @Async, then there will be parallel processing, but if the application crashes, then at a new start, messages will not be sent again.

```
@EventListener(condition = "#event.render")
public void startRender(GenericSpringEvent<RenderQueueObject> event) {
    RenderQueueObject render = event.getWhat();
    storageService.updateDocument(
            render.getGuid(),
            new Document("$set", new Document("dateStartRendering", new Date()).append("status", State.rendering.toString()))
    );
    Future<RenderWorkObject> submit = taskExecutor.submit(new RenderExecutor(render));
    try {
        completeResult(submit);
    } catch (IOException | ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
        log.info("Error when complete results after invoke executors");
    }
}

private void completeResult(Future<RenderWorkObject> renderFuture) throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    RenderWorkObject renderWorkObject = renderFuture.get();
    State currentState = renderWorkObject.getState();
    if (Stream.of(result, error, cancel).anyMatch(isEqual(currentState))) {
       storageService.updateDocument(renderWorkObject.getGuidJob(), new Document("$set", toUpdate));
    }
}
```

I tried to customize the configuration to fit my needs. But it didn’t work:

```
@Bean
Queue queue() {
    return Queues.RENDER;
}

@Bean
TopicExchange exchange() {
    return Exchanges.EXC_RENDER;
}

@Bean
Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(Queues.RENDER_NAME);
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(@Qualifier("defaultConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    return template;
}
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(@Qualifier("defaultConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, RabbitEventListener listenerAdapter) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(Queues.RENDER_NAME);
    container.setQueues(Queues.RENDER);
    container.setExposeListenerChannel(true);
    container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(20);
    container.setConcurrentConsumers(10);
    container.setPrefetchCount(1000);
    container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
    return container;
}
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory defaultConnectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory cf = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    cf.setAddresses("127.0.0.1:5672");
    cf.setUsername("guest");
    cf.setPassword("guest");
    cf.setVirtualHost("/");
    cf.setPublisherConfirms(true);
    cf.setPublisherReturns(true);
    cf.setChannelCacheSize(25);

    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
    cf.setExecutor(es);
    return cf;
}
```

I would be grateful for any idea

Comment: "messages must be guaranteed to be delivered even if the application crashes" - that cannot be done, not even synchronously. If the thing crashes, it completely stops.

Comment: @f1sh No, it works synchronously. I have several instances of the application running nearby. If application A fails, a message is sent to application B again and the process starts again. If many messages are sent at once, then they will take up free application instances. And that could be a solution. But it is impossible to run many applications at once nearby, since this requires too much memory. Therefore, I have to process all incoming messages asynchronously. And in case of failure they should be sent again.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are trying to do. You already have concurrency set on your listener containers (10-20) so you don't need to do the `send()` asynchronously because you already have at least 10 threads consuming data.

Comment: @GaryRussell No, I do not want to send asynchronously. I will accept and process asynchronously. But I have to do this so that in case of crash, the message is sent to me again. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: @GaryRussell I do this check: I launch my application. I imitate the work of some handler by setting Thread.sleep (100000). I configure the handler to work asynchronously using ThreadPoolExecutor. I send several messages to the queue at once. Without waiting for the end of 100,000 milliseconds, I stop the application. And again I launch it. I expect all messages to be retrieved and processed by my handler. But this does not happen.

Comment: I look at the logs and see that my consumers are now working in parallel. In case of crash, messages are sent. But they are processed sequentially, in one thread. Is it possible to fix something, so that in the event of a crash, messages are launched for processing in parallel?

Comment: I found that if one instance of the application, in which there was an asynchronous handler, crashed, then in the second instance, processing starts asynchronously as well. But if all the instances crashed, then after they are restarted, synchronous processing takes place.

Comment: `> No, I do not want to send asynchronously. ` ?? - you are sending from an `@Async` event listener. `>But they are processed sequentially, in one thread.` That is probably due to the prefetch (default 250); you will have messages prefetched in the sleeping processor; you can reduce the prefetch count to 1 (but that will degrade performance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution. I changed the RenderRabbitEventListener so that it again sent the message to the queue if the message was received from Rabbit in case of crash. Thanks to this, my consumer will always work in parallel. This will work in parallel in the event of a failure of all nodes, as well as in the event of a failure of one node.

Here are the changes I made:

```
@RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(value = @Queue(Queues.RENDER_NAME),
        exchange = @Exchange(value = Exchanges.EXC_RENDER_NAME, type = "topic"),
        key = "render.#")
)
public void onMessage(Message message, Channel channel,
                      @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long tag
) {
    RenderQueueObject queueObject = parseRender(message, RenderQueueObject.class);
    if (message.getMessageProperties().isRedelivered()) {
        log.info("Message Redelivered, try also");
        try {
            channel.basicAck(tag, false);
            MessageConverter messageConverter = rabbitTemplate.getMessageConverter();
            String valueAsString = parseBody(message);
            Message copyMessage = messageConverter.toMessage(valueAsString, new MessageProperties());
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(
                    message.getMessageProperties().getReceivedRoutingKey(),
                    copyMessage);
            return;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.info("basicAck exception");
        }
    }
    log.info("message not redelievered");
    String routingKey = parseRoutingKey(message);
    log.debug(String.format("Event %s", routingKey));
    handleMessage(queueObject);
}
```